Keep track of employee activities
Which one of following expressions is suitable for a write up which covers daily activity of an employee in an organization:

Activity Log

Activity Diary



Welcome to ELL. Your phrasing, “Which one … is suitable,” implies that one of them is. So, do you believe so? Based on what?

That's what I believe.......

What do you mean by "a write up"? Usually, an [activity] log is a document an employee updates "in real time" (immediately before or after doing each task, or at the end of each working day) for the purpose of billing the customer. And usually, an [activity] diary is where the employee writes in his future tasks / appointments / etc. so he and other workers in the same office can see when he's available for other appointments, and when he's already booked.

I mean a record of whatever an employee do every day....

what an employee does every day.

using the term calendar is probably more suitable than activity diary

There are many names that this type of thing might be called, and they vary by region. You haven't specified whether you're looking for BrE or AmE or some other dialect (not to mention that there are regional words in different areas of the US alone). Different industries or professions may also have their own term for a record of employee activity. However, here are some common names you might hear this called:

Activity Log - If you use this in context, everyone will know what you mean. Without other information about region or industry, it is likely the best option.
Activity Report - This may actually be more common than activity log but implies a more polished "report" rather than just a list of times and tasks. It may contain notes or be formatted in some specific way.
Time Tracker / Time Log - These are common terms in the US to have created a genre of apps to help employees manage their time called "Time Tracking Apps"
Billing Log - In some industries, employees bill clients directly based on how much time was spent on specific tasks. Using this term implies that this type of payment is present.

